# why is っていう in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

別に言い伝えがあるっていうだけだよ

How does it differ from just 別に言い伝えがあるだけだよ?

Answer (score -1):

The って in っていう is a contraction of the と in という which is used to quote something and is usually translated as "That is to say" or "That is" or something like that (depends on the context) and sometimes it gets lost in translation (unless you are translating literally).

Here the quotation is applied to 「別に言い伝えがある」so「別に言い伝えがあるっていうだけだよ」would translate into "That's just another (not especially interesting\important\unique\special) legend\tradition, you know".

Without っていう it would translate as "There is just another legend, you know" which is kind of weird.

Here are two videos explaining more about the と particle for quotation:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dYT6Xf1BkA
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40avkmkQR8M

Comment: Do we really not have a duplicate for the basic general use of this って? I couldn't find a good target but it seems commonly asked.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I only found some questions about relatively specialized usages. Nothing about the vanilla っていう. If you find one please do link it here.

Comment: この「別に」は、another とか just another って意味じゃないです。「別に～って(いう)だけ」のような形で、「重要ではない、問題ではない、単に～というだけのことだ」ってことを表す表現です。この「別に」と同じ感じです：https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34626/9831